# synchronizing file output in a static class

Tags: java, multithreading

I have several threads which need to write to two different text files. So far I have this code:

```
public class Logger {

    public static void printToGameLog(String value){
        Writer writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream("GameLog.txt", true), "utf-8"));
            synchronized(writer){
                writer.write(outputString + "\r\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex){
            System.out.println("cannot create log file");
        } 
    }


    public static void printToServerLog(String value){
        Writer writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream("serverLog.txt", true), "utf-8"));
            synchronized(writer){
                writer.write(outputString + "\r\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex){
            System.out.println("cannot create log file");
        }
    }
}
```

Is this an acceptable way of ensuring no more than one thread is writing to the same file at the same time?

If a thread calls one of these methods and enters the sync block, then what happens if another thread comes along and tries to execute the same method. When it tries to use the local variable `writer`, will it try and obtain the same object that has been locked by the other thread and therefore block? I would have thought that it would simply create its own separate variable, which would mean I should make writer a static class variable instead?

Comment: There is no need to sync if you are writing to 2 different files.

Comment: Don't use `"\r\n"` -- use `"\n"` only and let the runtime write the correct line endings for the platform.

Comment: Is your objective to coordinate output to both GameLog and ServerLog, or merely to prevent two threads from interleaving within a single output line?

Comment: I believe the latter. I have a situation where two threads may try to write to same file at the same time. Thanks for the \r tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are separate log files, I don't see why you need to have class-level synchronization.  Seems like a needless bottleneck.  I'd provide sync for each method separately (since it's fine for them to hit separate files simultaneously):

```
public class Logger
{
    private static final Object GAME_LOG_LOCK = new Object();
    private static final Object SERVER_LOG_LOCK = new Object();

    public static void printToGameLog(String value){
        synchronized (GAME_LOG_LOCK) {
            Writer writer = null;
            try {
                writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    new FileOutputStream("GameLog.txt", true), "utf-8"));
                writer.write(outputString + "\r\n");
            } catch (IOException ex){
                System.out.println("cannot create log file");
            } 
        }
    }

    public static void printToServerLog(String value){
        synchronized (SERVER_LOG_LOCK) {   
            Writer writer = null;
            try {
                writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    new FileOutputStream("serverLog.txt", true), "utf-8"));
                writer.write(outputString + "\r\n");
            } catch (IOException ex){
                  System.out.println("cannot create log file");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @RogerJarvis You also need to close the file in each case.

Answer (score 0):

That's a null pointer exception in your code, try this way of using the synchronized block on a static method

```
   synchronized(Logger.class){
```

or another alternative is to set the whole methods synchronized, like this

```
public static synchronized void printToGameLog(String value){
```

and

```
public static synchronized void printToServerLog(String value){
```

I'm not convinced that you need synchronization in here, you only need synchronization if you have a state that is being read/written from multiple threads.

Comment: Oops silly me. Of course that is going to give NPE. I guess I will reword my question to sync on the writer after it has been initialized. With your suggestion however, doesn't this mean that whilst one thread is writing to the gameLog, that another thread can be blocked from writing to the serverLog?

Comment: yes, I though that's what you wanted to do, I realize now that I misread your queestion

Answer (score 0):

Here is another take on your problem. It uses a single thread to write the log file and only this thread has access to the files. The threads that have to log something write against a BlockingQueue:

```
public class ThreadedLog {

    //This is some code to test the logger
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, FileNotFoundException {

        ThreadedLog log = new ThreadedLog("/tmp/test.txt");
        // Start 100 thread that write against the log
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            new Thread(new TestLogger(log)).start();
        }
    }

    private static class TestLogger implements Runnable {

        private ThreadedLog log;

        public TestLogger(ThreadedLog log) {
            this.log = log;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
                try {
                    log.log("This is entry " + i + " from thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + " is done");
        }
    }
     //________________________________________________________________________________________________
    /*
     * This is the code for the actual logger
     *
     */
    private final BlockingQueue<String> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10000);
    private String fileName;
    private Thread thread;
    private Writer writer;

    public ThreadedLog(String fileName) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, FileNotFoundException {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        thread = new Thread(new LoggingThread());
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream(fileName, true), "utf-8"));
        thread.start();
    }

    private class LoggingThread implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                for (;;) {
                    ThreadedLog.this.writer.write(queue.take() + "\r\n");
                    ThreadedLog.this.writer.flush();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                try {
                    ThreadedLog.this.writer.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void log(String string) throws InterruptedException {
        queue.put(string);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I guess the benefit of this method would be that the threads would not ever have to spend time waiting for the lock to free up. I can't think of any disadvantages over the other method?

Comment: There is one disadvantage. If your application or server crashes and there are still some things to be logged in the queue, they are lost. If you can live with that, this might be a very good solution.